# get same tag value form xml by php DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a XML file, one part of the file is

```
<Images>
     <image_>image1.jpg</image_>
     <image_>image2.jpg</image_>
</Images>
```

I need the image names. I use the code like

```
$Images = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('Images');
foreach($Images as $Image){


    $Image = $Image->nodeValue."<br>";

    echo $Image;

    }
```

This is returns the imaged name but at a time as a string, I need as an array. I mean I want to insert the images in the database.
Some one help me.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Just put the `$Image->nodeValue`s into an array, and then into the database.

Comment: I put the value in an array get  Array ( [0] => image1.jpg image2.jpg ). I need Array ( [0] => image1.jpg,[1] => image2.jpg )

Comment: How are you making that array?

Comment: $val = array();
     foreach($Images as $Image){
      
      $Image = $Image->nodeValue;
      
      echo $Image;
      array_push($val,$Image);
      
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are looping over the `Images` element(s).  So, when you echo `nodeValue`, you are getting the value of the entire `Images` element (and all its children).

You need to loop over each of the `image_` elements (children) inside the `Images` element (parent)

```
$val = array();
$Images = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('Images');
foreach($Images as $Image){
    $imgs = $Image->getElementsByTagName('image_');
    foreach($imgs as $i){
        $img = $i->nodeValue;
        $val[] = $img;
        echo $img."<br>";
    }
}
var_dump($val);
```

Comment: I have got the currect ans. Thank you for helping.